# angular 7 how to inject http service into another service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject my `HTTP` service into another service. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I keep getting the error

> Can't resolve all parameters for GanttPropertyService: (?).

Here is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HttpService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    ...
}
```

appModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpService } from './services/shared/httpService';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpConfigInterceptor} from './services/shared/httpconfig.interceptor';
import {ErrorDialogService} from './services/shared/errorHandling/errorDialogueService'
import { GanttModule } from './gantt/gantt.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    GanttModule,

  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpConfigInterceptor, multi: true }, 
    HttpService,
    ErrorDialogService,    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm trying to use this `httpService` in the `GanttModule`
GantModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { GanttComponent } from './gantt.component';
import { GanttPropertyService} from '../services/gantt/ganttPropertyService';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule, MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { GanttToolBar } from './ganttToolBar/ganttToolBar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GanttComponent,
    GanttToolBar,
    ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDialogModule        
  ],
  providers: [
    GanttPropertyService,

  ]
})
export class GanttModule { }
```

Here is the service I'm trying to inject it in

```
import {HttpService} from '../shared/httpService';


export class GanttPropertyService{

    constructor(private http : HttpService){}

}
```

How can I use the `httpService` in the lower level module?`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a couple of things. You do not need to add `HttpService` to `providers` if you use `providedIn: 'root'` for that service. Also where is `@Injectable` for `GanttPropertyService`? Try adding `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` to `GanttPropertyService` and let us know if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating `GanttPropertyService` to make it an `@Injectable` service just like `HttpService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../shared/httpService';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GanttPropertyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpService){}
}
```

Also when using `providedIn: 'root'`, you do **not** need to add that respective service to the module's `providers` array. This makes a service a [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#singleton-services).

Hopefully that helps!